# Saving Binary Data To MySQLdb - Python

Tags: python, mysql, binary, blob

I have googled and searched this site, but nothing specific appears and cannot get this working. Here is the code:

```
    binData = ''.join(map(lambda x: chr(x % 256), attach.attcoll))

    sql_stmt = """INSERT INTO attachments (attno,filename,fileextension,projNo,procNo,wpattachment) \
    VALUES ('%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE filename='%s',fileextension='%s'""", attach.attno,\
attach.filename,attach.fileextension,attach.projNo,attach.procNo,binData,attach.filename,attach.fileextension

    try:
        cursor.execute(MySQLdb.escape_string(sql_stmt))
        conn.commit()
```

The attach.attcoll is data that comes in over JSON from an SQLite blob and java code on the client side. I then want to write binData to MySQL with MySQLdb, but keep getting a TypeError, and a return code of 500. Any ideas on how to fix this. I want to store binData into a MySQL blob.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bunch of things here:

```
binData = ''.join(map(lambda x: chr(x % 256), attach.attcoll))
sql_stmt = """INSERT INTO attachments (attno,filename,fileextension,projNo,procNo,wpattachment)
VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE filename=%s,fileextension=%s""" 

params = (attach.attno,attach.filename,attach.fileextension,attach.projNo,attach.procNo,binData,attach.filename,attach.fileextension)

cursor.execute(sql_stmt, params)
conn.commit()
```

A summary:

1. Make sure you are connected to the db first (if you don't know how to do this, read the MySQLdb documentation)
2. You don't want to escape your entire query, only the data parts, passing the statement and data separately to `cursor.execute()` means the cursor will escape it for you.
3. Dont quote your `'%s'`, MySQLdb does that for you as well.
4. Is your database transactional (i.e. InnoDB), is that why you are using `conn.commit()`, it is not necessary if you  aren't using  a  transactional engine.
5. Without seeing how you've structured your db table I can't guarantee this will work. As practice, have you tried creating a really simple database table and practiced inserting into it with MySQLdb, just so you familiarize yourself with the API?

Comment: 1. I am connected... 
2. Interesting...
3. Doesn't execute without those single quotes... at all. Will try again.
4. Well beyond that... the question is very specific to 'how to best store blob/binary data'. I am connected, if I eliminate binData from the script, all works fine - even with single quotes. The question stands alone because all other factors are accounted for.
Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: ok was just checking. there were a lot of things wrong with your query so wanted to make sure you were familiar with MySQLdb and cover all the bases i could think of

Comment: i dont understand how it works fine when you are escaping your entire query, furthermore, according to your code sql_stmt isnt a string, its a tuple, and MySQLdb.escape_string() raises an exception when given a tuple.

Comment: Thanks Jesse! Close! No TypeError any more, but still returning a 500. #2 in your checklist above was the key. Instead of inserts, I concatenated the strings around binData.

Comment: no quotes around `%s` here is a line from a working app of mine that stores jpgs in a mysql database:    `c.execute("""UPDATE items SET image=%s WHERE id=%s""",(img, id))`   img is a binary string, the raw contents of a jpg file

Comment: Bright light shines above head.... now I see what you are saying. Okay, took the escape strings and repositioned just around data pieces. Took quotes out too. Hmmm... confused on this and gotta RTFM.

Comment: Forehead slapper.... The code provided above works. Thank you. The http response returns a 500 though, so need to figure that out or figure out if I can just go on without sending a response.